# First row of results should never be displayed

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cc260d98b49ac783a5abd6a74ab53d5f)**

```
CREATE TABLE logistics (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    time_stamp DATE,
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO logistics
(time_stamp, quantity)
VALUES 
('2020-01-14', '100'),
('2020-01-15', '400'),
('2020-01-16', '530'),
('2020-01-17', '500');
```

**Expected Result**

```
time_stamp  |  quantity  |
------------|------------|------
2020-01-15  |    400     |
2020-01-16  |    530     |
2020-01-17  |    500     |
```

---

In the results I want to display the `quantity` for all dates **except for the first row**. 
I know in the example above I can do this with a simple `WHERE-condition` like this:

```
SELECT
l.time_stamp AS time_stamp, 
SUM(quantity) AS quantity
FROM logistics l
WHERE time_stamp <> '2020-01-14'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

However, it is neither guaranteed 
that the first `time_stamp` will be always `2020-01-14` 
nor that the `MIN(2020-01-14)` is always in the first row.

Therefore, I am wondering how I have to modify the query to **always not-display the first row** of the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is Postgresql, you can use the OFFSET clause.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html

```
SELECT
l.time_stamp AS time_stamp, 
SUM(quantity) AS quantity
FROM logistics l
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
OFFSET 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a WHERE condition with a sub-query

```
SELECT l.time_stamp, 
       SUM(quantity) AS quantity
FROM logistics l
WHERE time_stamp > (select min(time_stamp) from logistics)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use LIMIT OFFSET [clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html), for example:

```
SELECT
l.time_stamp AS time_stamp, 
SUM(quantity) AS quantity
FROM logistics l
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
LIMIT all OFFSET 1
;
```